# re methods in python to append string

Tags: python

In the below strings the regular expression would match both the conditions,

```
aa="192.168.251.135,henry,thesecond,0"
aa1="192.168.254.35,henry,0"
#The below regular expression would satisfy bot aa and aa1
re.findall(r"(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b),((?:\w+,\w+|\w+)),(\d+)",aa)
```

my question is that in the string `ab="192.168.251.135,henry,thesecond,"`If the integer is not present at the end, is it possible to append 1 in the output,by extending the above re.findall()

Comment: Please clarify your question: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If you observe the string it ends with a digit,if the string doesnt have any digit at the end i want to append1 in the result..

Comment: I have edited aa1 please look at it..

Comment: That' a like a CVS (use the cvs module to parse it), you don't need regular expressions, you can even aa.split(',') to get the results. RE are cool but you should try to avoid them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing. If my understanding is correct, you want to match the string even if the string does not end with a number. That would simply mean you need to change the regex so that the repetition of the last number match is 0 or more time instead of 1 or more times

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b),((?:\w+,\w+|\w+)),(\d*)",ab)
[('192.168.251.135', 'henry,thesecond', '')]
>>>
```

interestingly you can easily do this without regex

```
>>> if not ab.rpartition(",")[-1].isdigit():
    ab+='1'
```

Comment: @Rajeev: `*`, Zero or more times, `+` one or more times

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.isdigit()`.

```
if not aa[-1].isdigit():
    aa += '1'
```